# How to get network interface with API if the VM has guest agent disabeled

Tags: proxmox

I have an python code using proxmoxer to get the network-interfaces from VM, however it fails with an exception if guest agent is turned off for the VM. Is there any other way to get an network-interfaces information with API, having guest agent turned off
 `interface_info = node.qemu(vm_id).agent.get('network-get-interfaces')['result']`

Tried checking all endpoints in documentation of Proxmox API